# How do I use docker commands in docker container?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-machine, google-container-registry

I am using .gitlab-ci.yml file as below.
I want to perform docker pull & push to google container registry

```yaml
image:
  name: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  entrypoint: [ "" ]

variables:
  UNLEASH_IMAGE_NAME: "unleash"

stages:
  - print

print:
  stage: print
  script:
    - gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account $GCP_BUILD_SA
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_BUILD_ID
    - gcloud auth configure-docker
    - docker pull unleashorg/unleash-proxy:latest
    - docker tag unleashorg/unleash-proxy:latest gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_BUILD_ID/UNLEASH_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker images
```

I am getting below error in my pipeline when I run docker images just to test whether its working:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

1. I have tried entering the container & running the docker images command but same error.
2. I tried command service docker start & systemctl but these tools/commands are not there in container.

How do I resolve this issue. I just want to docker pull & push in this image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish a `Docker` image to `Container Registry` with `Gitlab` and use `Docker` in `Docker`, it's better using [Kaniko](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html), example for publish :

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

If you want to pull, then publish with a need to have `gcloud` cli, you can create your own `Docker` image from kaniko and install `gcloud` sdk inside.
Then you can publish this custom image to `Gitlab repo`, `GCP Container registry` or `GCP Artifact registry`, then use it from your `Gitlab` script :

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/custom-kaniko/v1.0.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - # tip your gcloud commands
    - # Adapt the Kaniko to fit to your need
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using Dockerfile & gcloud build command

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer helps for the initial question, can you mark it as solved to help newcomers ?